# xbacklight - No outputs have backlight property

Tags: lubuntu, brightness, backlight

I am running Lubuntu 16.04

Attempting to run `xbacklight -get` gives me `No outputs have backlight property`

There is only one directory in `/sys/class/backlight`, which is `intel_backlight`.

I have created an `xorg.conf` in `/etc/X11`:

```
Section "Device"
Identifier  "Card0"
Driver      "intel"
Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

Yet still no change.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem (under Debian) since the upgrade to the 4.6.0-1 kernel. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 9):

I don't know if you've solved this yet, but I was able to get to work by changing the name of the folder.

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Card0"
        Driver          "intel"
        Option          "Backlight"     "/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

I logged out after changing the path and when I logged back in `xbacklight` was working at is should. (I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 and I don't know if that makes much of a difference.)

Comment: I'm not the OP, but on ubuntu 18, I put this in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel-brightness.conf and it worked for me.  Thanks!

Comment: lubuntu 20_04, I have these files in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`, but no `intel`: `10-amdgpu.conf 10-quirks.conf 10-radeon.conf 40-libinput.conf 70-wacom.conf`. How can I move forward?

Comment: Works on Debian too.