# Cannot set brightness with xbacklight, Intel

Tags: drivers, xorg, intel-graphics, xrandr, xbacklight

This is similar to these two questions, but the solutions posted in each do not help me:

- [xbacklight - No outputs have backlight property](https://askubuntu.com/questions/790972/xbacklight-no-outputs-have-backlight-property)
- [xbacklight: No outputs have backlight property - No /sys/class/backlight folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715306/xbacklight-no-outputs-have-backlight-property-no-sys-class-backlight-folder)

I just got a Dell XPS 9380.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with the i3 window manager, and I'm trying to get nice hotkeys set up to change the backlight brightness, among other things.

I want to use [xbacklight](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/xbacklight.1.html) to alter the brightness. But it tells me "No outputs have backlight property", and indeed if I run `xrandr --verbose` I don't see backlight properties anywhere.

I *can* set the brightness by putting numbers in `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`, so I don't think I need to mess with any kernel options.

Now, the other questions' solutions, and the [section about xbacklight on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#xbacklight) say to add a Device section to the `xorg.conf` file, to set the `Backlight` option to `intel_backlight`.

All of the examples have `Driver` set to `intel`. When I do that and restart X, everything slows to a crawl, but I *can* use xbacklight successfully, and I see a backlight section in `xrandr --verbose`. But the CPU is pinned -- I think it's not really using the intel driver but rather a framebuffer. I don't know how to be sure. Here's an example configuration, which I put in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-video.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier "Card0"
        Driver "intel"
        Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
EndSection
```

If I instead set `Driver` to `i915`, everything is fast again, but xbacklight now gives the error again.

From searching the web I haven't been able to get a handle on what the difference is between `intel` and `i915`. I get the impression `i915` *is* the Intel driver, but then I'm not sure why all the examples set `Driver "intel"`. If they're different and I should be using `intel`, maybe I don't have that one installed? I tried installing the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` package, which required me to remove a bunch of other packages including `xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04` (these two both claim to be drivers for Intel i9xx), then setting `Driver "intel"`, but this resulted in a black screen I couldn't get out of (even with control-alt-F combos) and I had to reboot.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xbacklight` indeed does not work, unless, as you discovered, you greatly bring down the performance of your graphics.

On a Dell XPS 9350, I have been using a utility `light`. It is found on [GitHub](https://github.com/haikarainen/light#manual). Currently, .deb files are available for installation. Alternatively, the utility can easily be compiled (this was the only option when I first used it).

Your lines in i3-config then become:

```
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessUp exec  --no-startup-id light -A 5 # increase screen brightness
bindsym XF86MonBrightnessDown exec  --no-startup-id light -U 5 # decrease screen brightness
```

The drawback is that, thus far, this solution requires installing software outside of the Ubuntu repositories. The utility is currently available in the repositories of Fedora and Arch, though, so it is not unlikely that it will also make it to the Ubuntu repo one day.

Comment: Though this is definitely a good answer (and in fact I did come across `light` and am using it in the mean time), the reason I'm asking specifically about xbacklight are: 1. I don't understand why it doesn't work, given that I can set the brightness via the pseudofiles in /sys -- do you know why? // 2. I wanted to use [polybar](https://github.com/polybar/polybar), whose brightness plugin uses xbacklight.

Comment: Make this more clear at the start of your answer, and you will get more specific answer attempts. Currently it reads as if your main purpose is to set up nice hotkeys, and that is indeed what `light` can give you with little effort.

Comment: xbacklight is in the title, and the opening of one of the first paragraphs is "I want to use xbacklight". But I have found that it is possible using polybar's older "backlight" plugin (as opposed to "xbacklight") to have it read the backlight status, so all is well. Thanks.